# SUMIF formula with date criteria not working

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a sum if statement (in german):

```
=SUMMEWENNS(Rawdata!K2:K3446;Rawdata!I2:I3446;"bezahlt";Rawdata!A2:A3446;">= 04.03.2013 00:00";Rawdata!A2:A3446;"<= 10.03.2013 23:59")
```

I'm not sure why it doesn't work, cause I have checked the cells for formatting (TT.MM.JJJJ hh:mm)

The Shees where it gets the data from Looks like this:

```
======= A ======      == I ==  ==== K ====
04.03.2013 22:00      bezahlt     10,20 €
```

The formula gives me back "0" even though it should give me back the 10,20

Where is the mistake?

EDIT the formula editor gives me back the following:

[image]

What do I have to edit my formula to do get the right results???

2nd EDIT

Ok the formula works now. Now I only need to be able to copy it into a field via VBA
I seem to have a syntax problem:

```
Cells(5, fieldextsales).FormulaLocal = "=SUMMEWENNS(Rawdata!K2:K" & maxnumrows & ";Rawdata!I2:I" & maxnumrows & ";""bezahlt"";Rawdata!A2:A" & maxnumrows & ";"">= "&DATWERT(""& weekstart &" 23:59")";Rawdata!A2:A" & maxnumrows & ";""<= "&DATWERT(""& weekend & " 23:59"))"
```

Thx for the help

Comment: Have you tried using the formula wizard to break down each section of the list?

Comment: Are the date/time values that you are showing stored as formatted date values or as strings? A mismatch there is the most likely problem.

Comment: the date/time values in column A are formatted as date/time values. I have checked for formatting mismatches.

Answer (score 1):

If your cell date amounts are stored as formatted date amounts, change your formula to:

```
=SUMMEWENNS(Rawdata!K2:K3446;Rawdata!I2:I3446;"bezahlt";Rawdata!A2:A3446;">="&DATWERT("04.03.2013 00:00");Rawdata!A2:A3446;"<="&DATWERT("10.03.2013 23:59"))
```

Comment: I checked the formula wizard and it shows me the dates as strings. Looks like a unix timestamp. How is this possible? I formatted the the cells as date/time?

Comment: I have posted a picdump in the orgininal post

Comment: Try using DATWERT instead of DATEVALUE as that function's name. Oh, the values for column a in your picdump do look like Excel serial data values (which is good).

Comment: thx for the help! The formula works now. There is one more thing ;-) I have edited my original post#

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to @chuff's answer that doesn't rely on `DATEVALUE` to interpret the date format, you might try...

```
=SUMMEWENNS(Rawdata!K2:K3446;Rawdata!I2:I3446;"bezahlt";Rawdata!A2:A3446;">="&DATUM(2013;3;4);Rawdata!A2:A3446;"<"&DATUM(2013;3;11))
```

...where `DATUM` is the German name for the worksheet function named `DATE` in English.

Comment: I have checked the fommula wizard and posted a picdump in my original question... looks weired

Comment: that's normal-dates are stored as numbers with times being fractions of 1 day